# ASP.NET MVC RC2 template head after body?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I installed ASP.NET MVC RC2, I noticed that the template had changed from RC1. Now, all new views have the header placeholder after the main content place holder. Why is this? It seems very illogical to me and it most definitely was not the case with RC1. I googled but couldn't find any reasoning for this change. Do you know of any?

Example:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Rules</h2>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Note how the placeholder with ContentPlaceHolderID of "head" is at the bottom? Weird...

Comment: Noticed this as well, I end up cut and pasting it back to the top ;).

Comment: Yeah that's what I do too, but it's annoying and IMO, doesn't make sense. Probably just an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I noticed it when I upgraded, but it shouldn't matter. The two `<asp:Content>` sections get mapped by the `ID` property to their places as defined in `Site.master`.

Definitely check the order in `Site.master`, but it should be fine.

If you want to change this, you can look into the T4 template your views are using. Check out:

[t4-templates-in-asp.net-mvc](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/31/t4-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

[t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx)

[overriding-global-t4-templates-in-asp-net-mvc-project-with-per-project-templates](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2009/01/29/overriding-global-t4-templates-in-asp-net-mvc-project-with-per-project-templates.aspx)